# How To bind data to Word Dcoument as dynamically using c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

i have facing the problem with Bind data to Word Document as Dynamically.I have a  windows application in that i get the data from the data base to the data-set,when i click the button then data set values will bind to the word document.Please help me,how can achieve this task Please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at these MSDN articles -

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668208.aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfk2wb04.aspx